# ListTile with shape is not hidden on scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-list-tile

I have a ListView.separated with ListTiles which contains a shape: RoundedRectangleBorder.

Everything is displayed as I want. But when I scroll the ListView, the content within the ListTile is hidden but not the shape.
The ListView is in the Expanded as follow:

SafeArea

-- Padding

---- Column

------ Center

------ Expanded

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `ListView` in a `Material`. The shape is drawn on the underlying material. By giving it its own material it shouldn't be able to draw outside its bounds

Answer (score 0):

you can delete Expanded and add the listview in container and set height to container